# "Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files" - NextJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I'm having an issue with watchpack throwing this error above in a next app when I try to `next dev`.
The screen keeps rolling with the following pattern:

```
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user/Projects/project/sub-project/src/pages'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user/Projects/project/sub-project/src'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user/Projects/project/sub-project'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user/Projects/project'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user/Projects'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/my_user'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home'
```

Any ideia of what I can do to fix it? So far I have tried increasing the open files limit with `ulimit -n 65536` but with no success

Comment: got any solutions?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 4):

This error is because watchpack module.

Just add in .env:

```
   WATCHPACK_POLLING = true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but without address after 'watch'.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vtx8.jpg)

What I tried:

1. increase ulimit
2. increase sysctl maxfile limit
3. install watchman
4. restart computer and reinstall watchman

They all don't work. Finally, I removed the directory and recloned it from GitHub and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurred by watchpack module.

Make .env file and just add command in there:

```
WATCHPACK_POLLING = true
```